# why scanf scans a null value

Tags: c, scanf

In the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char *name;
  int age;  
  char *gen;

  printf("Your name:");
  scanf("%s",name);

  printf("Your age:");
  scanf("%d",&age);

  printf("Your gender:");
  scanf("%s",gen);

  printf("*****************\n");

  printf("%s is a %d years old %s \n",name,age,gen);

  return 0;  

}
```

When I run it like this:

```
Your name:tom
Your age:20
Your gender:male
*****************
tom is a 20 years old (null)
```

As you can see, gen is a null value, Why `scanf` fails reading into gen but the first two readings success?

Comment: so instead of char *name use char name[20] and char gen[20]

Comment: @Rob why `name` works without allocating memory to it but `gen` doesn't?

Comment: @user3289218 "luck". The worst symptom of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You're in nasal demon territory, *anything* can happen. Oh, and there is no null value in your code (or at least, no value guaranteed to be null; on a Microsoft debug environment, it's guaranteed *not* to be).

Comment: Yep Quentin is right.. You were lucky the pointer to name did not point to something vital. you basically wrote somewhere in memory, you could have written to un-allocated memory or corrupted another variable somewhere or messed up instructions for a function.. there is no way to know. Hence your code's behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char *name;
char *gen;
```

are just char pointer and point nothing. So need to allocate memory for it.

You can allocate memory for it like

```
char *name = malloc(100);
char *gen  = malloc(100);
```

OR define char array with predefined length

```
char name[100];
char gen[100];
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to specify the length of the char array, like `char name[10]`?

Comment: why does the name pointer works then, i tried swapping the scanf to read gen first, then name string went null.

Comment: @ralph This look me undefined behaviour.

Comment: but why do I have to allocate memory for it first?

Comment: @user3289218 Because these are pointer only, not pointed to any address. You have to first give address pointer to that pointer and using that these pointer traverse memory how much allocate for it.

Comment: And without allocating memory for `name`, why it worked but `gen` doesn't.

Comment: @user3289218 This may happen because of `sizeof(char *)` is may `4/8` in your machine and it allow to store you `3` char plus one `null` character. So `tom` will passed. Now try with more character then see what happen.

Comment: I tried with a very long string, `name` always works but `gen` never. Or we can say the first scan of chars always works but the second doesn't

Comment: @user3289218 The fact that your program "works" at all is a complete fluke, and should never be relied upon

Answer (score 1):

```
char *name;
char *gen;
```

Are pointer, you need either to change to array

```
char name[256];//256 is arbitrary ofc
char gen[256];
```

or to allocate memory with your pointer:

```
char *name = malloc(256 * sizeof(*name));
char *gen = malloc(256 * sizeof(*gen));
```

Note that if you allocate memory with malloc, it is a good habbit to check if the allocation failed:

```
if (name == NULL)
    return -1;
```

Comment: No need to type cast return of `malloc` and `sizeof(char)` always `1`. so no need for it.

Comment: I think it is a go habbit to cast malloc result, also sizeof is not needed here but for everythings else it is and as OP seem to be new to C, I don't want to confuse him. But I'll edit with more explaination

Comment: but why do I have to allocate memory for it first?

Comment: @mantal: You might consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576 then you perhaps agree with many that it's actually bad habbit to cast the result of malloc & friends.

Comment: Regarding the redundant use of `sizeof(char)`: Doing so `char * name = malloc(256 * sizeof(*name));` makes sense.

Comment: @alk I changed to sizeof(*name) thanks. But I'll let the cast because I still think it is better and also because after Jayesh edit, my answer is a bit redundant, it is better to show that you have more than one way to do things.

Comment: Yes, but I'm more convinced by this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14879184/3057566 Especially by the pointer part (* instead of ** ...).